# Error on collection_set_2_upload

Tags: sql-server

The following error appears in the Job history Log in SQL Server

An error occured while trying to access the cache directory: "D:\". Inner Error ------------------>  Access is denied.  Process Exit Code 4.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Has any one experienced this error before?

This is occuring during MDW collection_set_2_upload

Because of this the database log Becomes full.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collection_set_2_upload` seems to be a SQL Agent job related to MDW (Management Data Warehouse).  Look in your SQL Agent job activity and see if you see a failed job.

Of bigger importance was the fact that your log was full.  Clear that up first or you'll be going nowhere.

**EDIT**
From your comment, `dcexec` is a process that collects information to store performance stats on for reporting using MDW.  It could have given you that error because the log file was full.

Comment: Log was cleared.

Comment: It is definately a failed job, its in the log.

Comment: @Abby What's that job step trying to do?

Comment: dcexec -u -s 2 -i "$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(MACH))\$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(INST))"

Comment: That is the command of the step that fails.......

Comment: @Abby see my edit.  Is the job running again successfully after you cleared the log file?

Comment: it is still failing after the log was fixed...

Comment: @Abby do you have MDW isntalled on that instance?

Comment: yes.....I have to leave the office so I may not respond quickly, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ok, no problem.  Just wanted to make sure MDW was there and not removed leaving orphaned jobs or something like that.

Comment: How do I get this question reopened?

Comment: @Abby now that you've edited the question click the reopen link underneath the question body.  It'll take a few reopen votes to have it reopened.  You might also consider asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com intead.

Comment: There is no reopen link on my page... thanks for your help.

Comment: In the odd event anyone sees this and it can help them, I seemed to have figured out the problem. The "SQL USER", the one that SQL SERVER performs back -up as, needed to be given full control rights to the cache directory in question although it had full control right to the drive in question. changed that and the jobs worked normally.